# How to get data from another model and pass it to view in CakePHP?

Tags: php, templates, cakephp

I added this line in my controller :

```
public $uses = array('DemandeFormation','Formation');
```

i read it will allow me to use both Formation and DemandeFormation model in my controller : DemandeFormationsController

Here is my function, it seems functionnal to me :

```
public function lister($id=null) {
    $options=array('conditions' => array('DemandeFormation.utilisateur_id' => $id));
    $this->set('demandes',$this->DemandeFormation->find('all',$options));
    $this->set('formations',$this->Formation->find('all',$options));
}
```

lister.ctp content :

```
<?php
    foreach($demandes as $d)
    {
        $id=$d['DemandeFormation']['formation_id'];
        $nom=$formations['Formation'][$id];
        echo $nom;
    }
?>
```

after executing the action, i get two errors on the browser :

```
Undefined index: Formation [APP\View\DemandeFormations\lister.ctp]
Undefined index:  [APP\View\DemandeFormations\lister.ctp]
```

What's wrong with my code. I'll appreciate your help and advices.

Comment: You forgot to put `lister.ctp` content.

Comment: I added it. Quick response !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$formations` is returned by a `find('all')` so it's an array indexed by numeric key, like:

```
$formations = array(
    0 => array(
        'Formation' => array()
    ),
    1 => /* ... */
) ;
```

So you can't access `Formation` directly, you need to be able to access it using `id`.

The simplest way would be to add a `belongsTo` relationship in your `DemandeFormation` model:

```
class DemandeFormation extends AppModel {
    /* ... */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        /* Nothing more because you kept CakePHP foreign key style. */
        'Formation'
    ) ;
    /* ... */
}
```

Them, you don't need to retrieve the `Formation` using `find('all')` and can access your field using, in your `foreach` loop, simply:

```
$d['Formation']['name']
```

Where `name` is a field in the `Formation` table.

Comment: belongsTo relationship is already there between the two models !

Comment: @codeless So you don't need to use `Formation->find('all')` and can simply access the `Formation` linked to your `DemandeFormation` using the code at the end of my answer.

Comment: I did as you said, now i have another error :

Undefined offset: 3 [APP\View\DemandeFormations\lister.ctp

here is the new code :

foreach($demandes as $d)
{
 $id=$d['DemandeFormation']['formation_id'];
 $nom=$d['Formation'][$id];
 echo $nom;
}

end the new function :

public function lister($id=null) {
$options=array('conditions'=>array('DemandeFormation.utilisateur_id' => $id));
  $this->set('demandes',$this->DemandeFormation->find('all',$options));
}

Comment: It's not `$d['Formation'][$id]`, it's `$d['Formation']['name']` for example. The link between the `formation_id` and the `Formation.id` is automatically made by Cake when using relationship between model.

Comment: Now i understand my error. i give as parameter $id, which is a number. But it's like writing : $d['formation'][3] . So it gives me the error. You suggest me to put the name of the column of the table instead of $id. But i want a specific name. How do i do it ? thank's for your answers.

Comment: @codeless In your loop, `$d` is an instance of `DemandeFormation` which has an associated `Formation` row in your DB. Then, `$d['Formation']` is the associated row so you can access values of this row simply by doing `$d['Formation']['whatever field I want']`.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, i know i should have understood from your first answer. But this concept is new for me, and now i understand well the trick.
Thank you again :)